# Как защитить данные на сайте?

Tags: javascript, защита

Всем привет, я новичок в javascript. Я пишу интернет магазин, получаю товары с сервера, у них есть цена и название. После получения товаров я прохожусь по ним массивом и вставляю в HTML.

Как мне манипулировать с данными которые мне пришли с сервера? Где их хранить? Прямо в аттрибутах хтмл? Могу ли я тогда изменить цену прям в хтмл? Какие есть подходы хранения информации, чтобы например я не смог через хтмл сменить цену и купить товар? Если хранить только id товара, то его тоже можно изменить

Comment: не надо думать о том, что кто-то может изменить хтмл и изменить цену, ибо кто захочет вообще запрос отправит напрямую без всяких хтпмл и js. бэкенд при оформлении должен получить ID товара и количество и все расчитать самостоятельно.

Comment: какая разница как меняются данные на клиенте, если покупка все равно на сервере осуществляется? если придут некорректные данные, просто шли ошибку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вставлю две цитаты из комментариев и напишу маленькое резюме:

Вся визуальная часть - она только для клиента, чтобы было удобно куда-то переходить, куда-то нажимать, видеть сразу какие-то калькуляционные вычисления и пр. Просто, чтобы пользователю было удобно и комфортно пользоваться сайтом. Все же **критические действия**, например списание средств, происходит исключительно на серверной части, к которой клиент не имеет доступа. Там должна выполняться какая-то логика. И туда поступают простейшие данные: например идентификатор товара и количество для покупки.

---

> не надо думать о том, что кто-то может изменить хтмл и изменить цену,
> ибо кто захочет вообще запрос отправит напрямую без всяких хтпмл и js.
> бэкенд при оформлении должен получить ID товара и количество и все
> расчитать самостоятельно.

(с) [@teran](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/223826/teran)

> какая разница как меняются данные на клиенте, если покупка все равно
> на сервере осуществляется? если придут некорректные данные, просто шли
> ошибку

(c) [@Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy)

Comment: Касательно «простейших данных» у меня есть предоложение, что цену передавать тоже может быть полезно, например, для проверки, что цена с клиента совпадает с ценой, посчитанной логикой на сервере: пользователю может оказаться обидно, если из-за какой-нибудь рассинхронизации цен сервер спишет больше средств, чем было показано на клиенте

Comment: @andreymal что за рассинхронизация? Из-за кэша? А что должно происходить в таком случае?

Comment: Срок акции истёк, поставщик внезапно повысил цены, вкладка с кнопкой «Оплатить» провисела в браузере трое суток — мало ли что может случиться) Что должно происходить — каждый сам для себя решит наверно (хм, надо бы поэкспериментировать, как ведут себя настоящие интернет-магазины)